# Is ghusl required after e.g. reading lewd or inappropriate texts?

Tags: ghusl

I've only recently took ghusl but now even the slightest of things, even text, that could be considered lewd or inappropriate is making me think I need to take ghusl again. Is this a legitimate concern or is this not a problem?

I heard that ghusl is only necessary if it contained mani and that pre-ejaculatory fluid doesn't have any. But I've heard otherwise that pre-ejaculatory fluid *does* contain trace amounts of mani.

Comment: I think that the point is not whether what you emit contains maniy, but whether you climaxed.

Answer (score 1):

According to Islamic sources , Ghusl is only required, if post orgasm liquid comes out of the body (sperm), Or the male organ touches the female organ (even if intercourse does not happen). Other than that, there is no obligation to do ghusl if u read any such text. 
And there are never traces of sperm in the pre-ejaculation fluid, as it only comes after the orgasm, never before